# Visual Basic - Compile error: Invalid qualifier

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a custom Excel function in Visual Basic. When I run the function, I get the error: `Compile error: Invalid qualifier` on `mondayArray` on the line `For index = 0 To mondayArray.Length - 1`. What is causing this error?

```
Function SumHours(monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday)
    Dim mondayHours As Integer

    Dim mondayArray() As String
    Dim splitArray() As String

    SumHours = 0

    If monday <> "/" Then
        mondayArray = Split(monday, " ")

        For index = 0 To mondayArray.Length - 1
            splitArray = Split(mondayArray(index), "-")
        Next

    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

`.length` is not a property of an array. Use the [LBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) to determine the extents (Lower Boundary and Upper Boundary) of an array.

```
        For index = LBound(mondayArray) To UBound(mondayArray)
```

I believe you are confusing the `.length` property from a collection; e.g. HtmlElementCollection.